# Temperature Conversion Incorrect values

Tags: java, methods, data-conversion

So I have an assignment that requires us to create a script with two methods in it to convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit and from Fahrenheit to Celsius.

```
public static double celsiusTofahrenheit (double Celsius)

public static double fahrenheitToCelsius(double Fahrenheit)
```

I am trying to get the two methods to return the results of the conversion based on the number provided be the users input. Something seems to be wrong with my returns from the methods as the code gives the correct value i.e. converting Celsius to Fahrenheit but I cant this to work for the conversion of Fahrenheit to Celsius. Can someone clarify what I am doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TempConversionTest{ 

    public static double fahrenheit = 0.0;
    public static double celsius = 0.0;

    public static double celsiusToFahrenheit(double celsius){
    return 5.0/9.0 * fahrenheit - 32;
}

    public static double fahrenheitToCelsius(double fahrenheit){
        return 9.0/5.0 * celsius + 32;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

fahrenheit = 0;
celsius = 0;


System.out.println("Enter the Degrees in Fahrenheit");
fahrenheit = input.nextDouble();
celsius = celsiusToFahrenheit(celsius);
System.out.println(fahrenheit + " degrees Fahrenheit converted to Celsius   is: " + celsius);

System.out.println("Enter the Degrees in Celsius");
celsius = input.nextDouble();
fahrenheit = fahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit);
System.out.println(celsius + " degrees Celsius converted to Fahrenheit is: " + fahrenheit);
}

}
```

Comment: remove your static variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues here.

Firstly, your conversion methods are named wrong because the `celsiusToFahrenheit` actually tries to convert `fahrenheit` to `celcius` and vice versa.

Secondly, the conversion formula for `fahrenheit` to `celsius` (which is actually inside your `celsiusToFahrenheit()` method) should be as shown below. Notice, the **parentheses** `()` to override the operator precedence because the subtraction should happen first.

```
public static double celsiusToFahrenheit(double celsius){
    return 5.0/9.0 * (fahrenheit - 32);
}
```

Thirdly, your methods should be well encapsulated and **not** depend on **static** variables for input or output. So, the final implementation using the passed arguments correctly should look like

```
public static double celsiusToFahrenheit(double celsius){
    return 9.0/5.0 * celsius + 32;
}

public static double fahrenheitToCelsius(double fahrenheit){
    return 5.0/9.0 * (fahrenheit - 32);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your return statement in `fahrenheitToCelsius` should be

```
return (5.0 * (fahrenheit - 32)) / 9;
```

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but that's the wrong formula.

Comment: @pbabcdefp Maybe I'm too tired, but what is wrong with it ?

Comment: @pbabcdefp After testing, the result I get is the same as google.

Comment: I think it should be `return (5.0 * (Fahrenheit - 32)) / 9`.

Comment: no the downvoter, but obviously it does not make sense: you said it is `fahrenheitToCelsius` and of course it is supposed to have `fahrenheit` as input for the formula, but your formula is taking `celsius`

Comment: Unfortunately I am required to use the temperature conversions that I was given in my instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Your are passing celsius as a parameter but using fahrenheit in the method.

```
public static double celsiusToFahrenheit(double celsius){
   return 9.0/5.0 * celsius + 32;
}



public static double celsiusToFahrenheit(double fahrenheit){
   return 5.0/9.0 * (fahrenheit - 32);
}
```

Comment: The same algorithm reside in both of the method you pasted.

Comment: Thank you Trout but after replacing the method from double Celsius to double Fahrenheit I still get the incorrect value when running the script on the Fahrenheit conversion. My instructions are pretty specific, My methods are supposed to be kept as is in my original post as it is one of the things he is looking to grade on and the same goes for my conversions of temperature. If you can see anything else wrong or point me in the right direction I would appreciate it!

Comment: I always mismatch these formulas - since physics seventh grade ;))

Answer (score 1):

Don't use static variables for Celsius and Fahrenheit. Doing so in this case is just asking for exactly the trouble that you found. Instead use local variables within the static methods. Just remove the static variables from the class and you'll see what to do next.

BTW I think it's nicer to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit by `((C+40)*9/5.0 - 40)`. In other words, take the point where the two scales agree (-40 C = -40 F), move it to the origin, rescale, then move it back again.

Comment: Unfortunately i am being graded on using the conversion provided in my instructions. The option of creativity and play have been reduced to make grading easier I guess.

Comment: Too bad. Anyway, take a close look at your formulas. At least one of them is wrong ... order of operations.

Comment: A user above did point that out and made me realize how little the mistake was lol Thank you for helping Edward i see that I messed up my formula in the return for celsiusToFahrenheit by not playing my subtraction of the degrees by 32 in parentheses lol